# Can I access a static member of abstract class in a generic?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I'm trying to create a generic data exporter, where I can feed a bunch of rows and this can then get exported as excel, csv, etc...

To make it quick to specify I was planning on having the "headers" of the report specified on the same file as the rows, using static fields.

But this mess of having abstract classes with static members and the attempt of ussing them in a generic class is messy.

**Is there a clean way to do this?**

my attempt was having an abstract class with the base "interface" and a common method

```
public abstract class ReportRow
{
  public static readonly string[] ColumnNames;

  public static int ColumnCount => ColumnNames.Length;

  public string GetColumnValueAsString(int index)
  {
    var value = GetColumnValue(index);
    if (value is DateTime)
    {
      return value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }

    return value.ToString();
  }
}
```

then I have a couple of class implementations, I leave this one as an example:

```
public class OrdersReportRow : ReportRow
{
  public new static readonly string[] ColumnNames =
  {
    "Date", "StoreId", "StoreName", "SkuId", "Quantity"
  };
  
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public int StoreId { get; set; }
  public string StoreName { get; set; }
  public int SkuId { get; set; }
  public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
  
  public new dynamic GetColumnValue(int index)
  {
     return index switch
     {
       0 => Date,
       1 => StoreId,
       2 => StoreName,
       3 => SkuId,
       4 => Quantity,
       _ => throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(),
     };
  }
}
```

And the exporter class I wanted to be something like this:

```
public class ReportExporter<TReportRowType> where TReportRowType : ReportRow
{
  public void Export(IEnumerable<TReportRowType> reportEntries)
  {
    //code to add headers
    for (int i = 0; i < TReportRowType.ColumnCount; i++) // fails here because ColumnCount is not "visible"
    {
      AddColumn(TReportRowType.ColumnNames[i]); // also fails   
    }
    
    foreach(var entry in reportEntries) {
      for (int i = 0; i < TReportRowType.ColumnCount; i++) // fails here because ColumnCount is not "visible"
      {
        AddValue(entry.GetColumnValue(i));
        CommitLine()        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe that updating your question with something that compiles will improve the odds for getting good answers. BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those column names should be on a *collection or rows* level in my opinion. So that I would try something like this.

Note that the column names are automatically populated using reflection.

```
public abstract class ReportRow
{
    public abstract dynamic GetColumnValue(int index);

    public string GetColumnValueAsString(int index)
    {
        var value = GetColumnValue(index);
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
        return value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }
}

public abstract class ReportRows<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : ReportRow
{
    public string[] ColumnNames { get => _cols.ToArray();  }
    public int ColumnCount { get => _cols.Count; }

    List<string> _cols;
    List<T> _rows;

    public ReportRows() {
        _rows = new List<T>();

        _cols = new List<string>();
        var tt = typeof(T);
        foreach(var p in tt.GetProperties()) {
            _cols.Add(p.Name);
        }
    }

    public void Add(T row) => _rows.Add(row);

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _rows.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

public class OrdersReportRow : ReportRow
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public int SkuId { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    
    public override dynamic GetColumnValue(int index)
    {
        return index switch
        {
        0 => Date,
        1 => StoreId,
        2 => StoreName,
        3 => SkuId,
        4 => Quantity,
        _ => throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(),
        };
    }
}

public class OrdersReportRows : ReportRows<OrdersReportRow> { }

public class ReportExporter
{
    public void Export<T>(ReportRows<T> reportEntries) where T : ReportRow
    {
        //code to add headers
        for (int i = 0; i < reportEntries.ColumnCount; i++) // fails here because ColumnCount is not "visible"
        {
            AddColumn(reportEntries.ColumnNames[i]); // also fails
        }
        
        foreach(var entry in reportEntries) {
            for (int i = 0; i < reportEntries.ColumnCount; i++) // fails here because ColumnCount is not "visible"
            {
                AddValue(entry.GetColumnValue(i));
                CommitLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddColumn(string s) {}
    public void AddValue(object s) {}
    public void CommitLine() {}
}
```

to call:

```
var or = new OrdersReportRows();
or.Add(new OrdersReportRow { Date = DateTime.Now });

var re = new ReportExporter();
re.Export(or);
```

Comment: I do like this solution a lot. But how can I add and consume data into a OrdersReportRows class?

in the past I had just an IEnumerable<OrderReportRow> and I could add to it by doing yield returns in the method that generated it.so I could have something like:
ReportExporter(GetOrders()) and the data was being retrienved from sql and writen line by line at the same time.

Comment: By moving the code that uses reflexion to my exporter class, I was able to have the IEnumerable behavior and I dont need the ReportRows classes. This code did helped me a lot thou, thanks.

Comment: one important note thou GetProperties() does not guarantee that the order of the properties is the order of declaration. (So far it seems to work, I've added a unit test in to be aware if this changes in the future)

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using "new" for a method/property/field signature, I'd avoid the static public members (in combination with new). You can still use a static private field for implementation, but it's cleaner and easier to make the accessors for that field, i.e. the column names array and column count, non-static and abstract. At least "ColumnNames" should be abstract.

Sth like (untested):

```
    public abstract class ReportRow
    {
       public abstract string[] ColumnNames { get; }
       public int ColumnCount => ColumnNames.Length;

       public string GetColumnValueAsString(int index)
       {
         //as is
       }
   }

    public class OrdersReportRow : ReportRow
    {
      private static readonly string[] _columnNames =
      {
        "Date", "StoreId", "StoreName", "SkuId", "Quantity"
      };
    
      public override string[] ColumnNames => _columnNames;
    
      //no other changes ...
    }
    
    public class ReportExporter<TReportRowType> where TReportRowType : ReportRow
    {
        public void Export(IEnumerable<TReportRowType> reportEntries)
        {
           var firstEntry = reportEntries.FirstOrDefault();
           if (firstEntry == null) return;
           for (int i = 0; i < firstEntry.ColumnCount; i++) // shouldn't fail any longer, because ColumnCount is now "visible"
           {
             AddColumn(firstEntry.ColumnNames[i]); // also should work
           }
        
        foreach(var entry in reportEntries) {
          for (int i = 0; i < entry.ColumnCount; i++) // shouldn't fail any longer, because ColumnCount is now "visible"
          {
            AddValue(entry.GetColumnValue(i));
            CommitLine()        
          }
        }
      }
```